# facebook notification graphs method is now deprecated, but docs doesn't have new method

Tags: facebook, graph, notifications, push

trying to set up a facebook app for notifications, but the graph /user_id/notifications is now "old"

"message": "(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission manage_notifications is deprecated",

in the docs, they write about it, it's from 04/30/2019 but there is no new method, so I guess they truncate all the notifications from the apps?

Comment: see my answer. additional input: please include a link to the doc if you mention them, it is a lot easier to help when all the relevant details don´t need to be researched first. in that case though, the answer is pretty clear.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/notification

Comment: oh, ok > "This is an API that's only available for Pages." - access to user notifications is gone since many years though, as i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That endpoint is gone since several years, and there is no alternative way to access user notifications. I assume the date you mentioned is just some date of the last page update, it is definitely not related to the deprecation of `manage_notifications`.

There is also a possibility to send "App to User" notifications though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: This is confusing. You claim it's still a possibility to send "App to User" notifications, but the link you provided, points to endpoint: `/user_id/notifications`. Attempt to access this endpoint results in the same message as stated in the question: `(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission manage_notifications is deprecated`. So, is there any way to send "App to User" notifications or not?

Comment: did you try with a GET or a POST request? accessing notifications is not possible anymore, but sending app-to-user notifications should still work. it´s a one way thing.